# is there any API for selecting Bingmap polyline to be edited on drawing manager?

Tags: gis, bing-maps

is there any API for selecting and editing Bingmap polyline on drawing manager? 
I've tried to find some method about DrawingManager Class and Polyline Class for that and I got some method about setting edit drawing mode but that wasn't what I want exactly. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmDn9.png)
I want to select and edit polyline on edit mode of Drawing manager like above picture. 
I mean i found a API for "1. set edit mode" but couldn't found any API for "2. select a polyline to be edited"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve that problem by using edit method of DrawingTools class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt750463.aspx